# How to use C# Regular Expression Lookbehind with line anchors

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am having trouble with look-behind assertions in C#'s regular expression matching when also using line-begin & line-end anchors.
In the sample below, Regex B behaves exactly as I expect (and as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

I was initially surprised that RegEx A did not match Line 1.  Now I think I understand why RegEx A does NOT match line 1. [because the assertion is zero width - the expression is basically ^\d{2}$, which clearly doesn't match a 4 digit year - which is why it matches lines 6 & 7].

I know I can rewrite the positive assertion (RegEx A) like this: ^19\d{2}$.

But my ultimate goal is a regular expression like RegEx C - using a negative assertion to find all the strings that don't start with a given prefix. That is, I am trying to create a expression with a negative assertion that returns true for Lines 3 and 4 and not 5-7.

RegEx D is a similar negative-assertion sample from the C# documentation, but doesn't use begin/end anchors, and is true for lines 3 and 4, but also 5-7.

With that in mind, how can I make negative assertions (like RegEx C) work with line-begin/-end anchors so that it functions like the example from RegEx D while validating the input is a single line?

I'm wondering if this is simply not possible using assertions.  That would mean the alternative is to express all the positive cases that evaluate to the negation of the exception (similar to using 19 in Regex E), but it's either impossible or impractical to express a large set of positives when the goal is to exclude a particular single (perhaps-complex) case.

Thanks!

Sample Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] reList = new string[]
            {
                @"^(?<=19)\d{2}$",   // RegEx A
                @"(?<=19)\d{2}",     // RegEx B
                @"^(?<!19)\d{2}$",   // RegEx C
                @"(?<!19)\d{2}\b",   // RegEx D
                @"^19\d{2}$",        // RegEx E
            };

            string[] tests = new string[]
            {
                "1999",                     // Line 1
                "1851 1999 1950 1905 2003", // Line 2
                "1895",                     // Line 3
                "2095",                     // Line 4
                "195",                      // Line 5
                "18",                       // Line 6
                "19",                       // Line 7
            };
            foreach (var r in reList)
            {
                var re = new Regex(r);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine($"{r}");
                Console.WriteLine("==========================");
                foreach (var s in tests)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{s}={re.IsMatch(s)}");
                    if (re.IsMatch(s))
                    {
                        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(s))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Match @ ({m.Index}, {m.Length})");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
^(?<=19)\d{2}$
==========================
1999=False
1851 1999 1950 1905 2003=False
1895=False
2095=False
195=False
18=False
19=False

(?<=19)\d{2}
==========================
1999=True
Match @ (2, 2)
1851 1999 1950 1905 2003=True
Match @ (7, 2)
Match @ (12, 2)
Match @ (17, 2)
1895=False
2095=False
195=False
18=False
19=False

^(?<!19)\d{2}$
==========================
1999=False
1851 1999 1950 1905 2003=False
1895=False
2095=False
195=False
18=True
Match @ (0, 2)
19=True
Match @ (0, 2)

(?<!19)\d{2}\b
==========================
1999=False
1851 1999 1950 1905 2003=True
Match @ (2, 2)
Match @ (22, 2)
1895=True
Match @ (2, 2)
2095=True
Match @ (2, 2)
195=True
Match @ (1, 2)
18=True
Match @ (0, 2)
19=True
Match @ (0, 2)

^19\d{2}$
==========================
1999=True
Match @ (0, 4)
1851 1999 1950 1905 2003=False
1895=False
2095=False
195=False
18=False
19=False
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what output you want. Regex D doesn't have line begin/end markers so what do you mean make C work like D? What is wrong with C?

Comment: The question does need some clarification, but do you mean to use the negative lookahead function? Something like: ^(?!19)\d{4}$ ?

Comment: @NetMage - True for lines 3 & 4, false for 5-7.

Comment: What about `^(?<!19)\d{4}$` ?

Comment: @NetMage - the negative assertion matches any 4 digit number (including 1999)

Comment: @Brad Did you try my suggestion? Assert that it does not begin with 19 and is made of 4 digits, which consist a full line...  is a negative assertion. sounds about what you need, no? Did you mean only using lookbehind specifically? That would be a bit backwards in my book...

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Yes I did and that worked.  apologies for not voting your comment.

Comment: Fairly simple ... `^(?<=19)` Never matches _anything_: for multi-line mode, there is always a `\r\n(here)^`, for normal mode, there is nothing before
the beginning of string. The same is said for `^(?<!19)` but in reverse, this will match _everything_. So, that aside, whatever else doesn't
match is because of the rest of your regex.

Comment: An fyi. Think of it this way: `^(?<=19)` without the assertion is `19^`, there can never be anything except a line-break before the beginning of the line, and if it's at the beginning of string, nothing can exist. However, this is valid `^(?<=19\r?\n)` if in multi-line mode.

Comment: @Brad I upvoted the accepted answer, it's more complete and comes with a better explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing lookaround assertions with default behavior of a normal pattern. A lookaround asserts that means it doesn't consume characters.

It looks for a condition, if it satisfies then brings back cursor at where it began  otherwise it makes engine to backtrack or fail immediately.

Regex A `^(?<!19)\d{2}$` should not match string 1 `1999` because engine works this way:

1. `^` Assert beginning of string (we are at position 0)
2. `(?<!19)` Check if preceding characters are not `19` (for sure at
   position 0 we don't have a preceding character so this satisfies)
3. `\d{2}` Consume two digits (we are at position 2)
4. `$` Assert end of string (Actually we have 2 more characters to reach
   end of string so engine fails immediately)

So you have to do this `^\d{2}(?<!19)\d{2}$` or `^(?!19)\d{4}$` that the second is more suitable.

Comment: Good explanation of assertions, so upvoted, but didn't answer the full question.

Comment: I added a last line to the answer which points to the right solution. @Brad

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Providing both alternatives makes the behavior crystal clear and provides the lookbehind alternative if (for example) I wanted to capture only the last 2 digits.

Comment: For negative lookahead you can capture last two digits too by separating them: `^(?!19)\d{2}(\d{2})$`